# Finding the combination

Tags: combinatorics

I have this formula:

$$\frac{(N-K)(N-K-1)\cdots(N-K-n+1)}{N(N-1)\cdots(N-n+1)}$$

and my book says it can be written like this:

$$
\frac{\binom {N-n}K}{\binom N K}
$$

The problem is i cannot understand how they got to that result. I have been trying to calculate my way back from it to my original formula, but it doesn't give me the right result.
Please be patient with me, I am a beginner. And sorry that I've put it in as an image, i don't know how to write it here.

Update: My formula comes from calculating draws, without replacement:
I have $N$ balls, of which $K$ are white and I want to calculate the probability of not getting a white one in the first $n$ draws.
So $$
\begin{align}
P(1) & = \frac{N-K}{N} \\[6pt]
P(2) & = \frac{(N-K)(N-K-1)}{N(N-1)} \\[6pt]
P(n) & = \frac{(N-K)(N-K-1)\cdots(N-K-n+1)}{N(N-1)\cdots(N-n+1)}
\end{align}
$$
I am following a paper on the subject, and so far I was understanding, but I got stuck at 
$$
\frac{\binom {N-n}K}{\binom N K}
$$

Comment: Hit "edit" on @Henry's answer or this comment to see how to write $\binom{N}{K}$ in these pages.

Comment: Edited the image away, but I changed it to the right answer. The image may have shown something different.

Comment: @Ragnar: The image *did* show something different, and since it’s an image of printed text, it’s likely to be correct. I’m restoring what it actually said. The error is likelier to be in the other expression.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, yes, you're probably right about that

Comment: Casandra, the two expressions are in fact not equal. Are you sure that the first isn’t $$\frac{(N-n)(N-n-1)\ldots(N-n-K+1)}{N(N-1)\ldots(N-K+1)}\;?$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, you overlooked an "$n$" in your restoration.  I re-restored it....

Comment: @Barry: Yep, you beat me to it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answers. It is about the probability distribution for drawing without replacement, until first success. So the formula should calculate the probability of not getting white balls for n times, where N is the total number of balls and K is the number of white balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to see that the two expressions are equal without going through all the factorial computations.

As the OP notes, the first displayed formula, which can be thought of as written in the form

$${N-K\over N}\cdot{N-K-1\over N-1}\cdot{N-K-2\over N-2}\cdots{N-K-{n-1}\over N-(n-1)}$$

calculates the probability that you do not choose any of the $K$ white balls in the first $n$ draws when drawing without replacement from among $N$ balls.  But another way to compute this probability is to imagine lining up $N$ *uncolored* balls in the order in which they'll be drawn (not stopping after $n$ draws) and then picking $K$ balls at random to be colored white.  The total number of ways to pick $K$ balls is $N\choose K$; the number of ways to do so while avoiding the first $n$ balls is $N-n\choose K$.  So the probability is the quotient of those, or

$${N-n\choose K}\over{N\choose K}$$

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It does seem as if your second formula may have a typo since</strike>
$\require{cancel}$
$$\xcancel{
\begin{align}
\frac{(N-K)(N-K-1)\cdots(N-K-n+1)}{N(N-1)\cdots(N-n+1)}
&=\frac{\frac{(N-K)!}{(N-K-n)!}}{\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{\frac{(N-K)!}{(N-K-n)!\,n!}}{\frac{N!}{(N-n)!\,n!}}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{\binom{N-K}{n}}{\binom{N}{n}}
\end{align}}
$$

---

Seeing Barry Cipra's comment, I feel quite foolish. I have used this identity in many answers. Here is a corrected answer.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(N-K)(N-K-1)\cdots(N-K-n+1)}{N(N-1)\cdots(N-n+1)}
&=\frac{\frac{\color{#C00000}{(N-K)!}}{(N-K-n)!}}{\frac{N!}{\color{#00A000}{(N-n)!}}}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{\frac{\color{#00A000}{(N-n)!}}{(N-K-n)!}}{\frac{N!}{\color{#C00000}{(N-K)!}}}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{\frac{(N-n)!}{(N-K-n)!\,K!}}{\frac{N!}{(N-K)!\,K!}}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{\binom{N-n}{K}}{\binom{N}{K}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: There is no typo.  Instead there is an identity:  $${{N-K\choose n}\over{N\choose n}}={{N-n\choose K}\over{N\choose K}}$$ which you can verify with factorials or via two ways of computing probabilities (see my answer).

Comment: @BarryCipra: thanks for noting this. I feel abashed.

Comment: I have felt (and been) foolish so many times I am long since past the point of feeling abashed....

Comment: @BarryCipra: in any case, it gave me a chance to try out the "cancel" package. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$N(N-1)\cdots(N-n+1) = \dfrac{N!}{(N-n)!} = n!{N \choose n}$$

You may have a typo in your original question, confusing $n$ and $K$

Answer (score 0):

$\dbinom{N-n}{K}=\dfrac{(N-n)!}{K![K-(N-n)]!}$ & $\dbinom{N}{K}=\dfrac{N!}{K!(K-N)!}$.. taking ratio of these
 $\frac {\dbinom{N-n}{K}}{\dbinom{N}{K}}=\frac{\dfrac{(N-n)!}{K![K-(N-n)]!}}{\dfrac{N!}{K!(K-N)!}}$=$\dfrac{(N-n)! K!(K-N)!}{K!N![K-(N-n)]!}$=$\dfrac{(N-n)! (K-N)!}{N![(K-N)+n]!}$.... Hope you can do it from here.

Answer (score 0):

just use the combination formula for \begin{pmatrix}N-n\\K\end{pmatrix}and \begin{pmatrix}N\\K\end{pmatrix} separately and do the simplification. Go from R.H.S. to L.H.S. or say answer to question.

That will be easier to understand.